# Python Tkinter entry-point

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So for a project on my school I am trying to make an GUI where I can add some info for some email so it will send it automatically through an python script.

Now I do have a small problem. I made some entry-points but for some reason I can not add text to the left of the entr-ypoints. Does anyone know how to do that?

I am trying to get 'sending to:', 'name:', and 'course:' to the left of the corresponding entry-points.

It might sounds silly, but please do not change to much of the actual code. It has to be like this for the project.

Kind regards,

Allard

```
import os
import smtplib
import tkinter as tk

root =tk.Tk()

root.title("Title")

def main():

    USER = os.environ.get('USERNAME_GMAIL')
    PASSWORD = os.environ.get('PASSWORD_GMAIL')
    print("-"*60)
    print("\nNew Email\n\n")


    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as smtp:

        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(USER, PASSWORD)



        PROFESSOR = entry2.get() 
        COURSE = entry3.get()

        subject = 'Course literature: ' + COURSE
        body = 'Body of the email, doesnt really matter whats in here' + PROFESSOR

        msg= f'Subject:{subject}\n\n{body} '

        smtp.sendmail(USER, RECEIVER, msg)


canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width= 400)
canvas1.pack()

entry1=tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 60, window=entry1)

entry2=tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 80, window=entry2)

entry3=tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=entry3)



def PRINT():
    x1 = entry1.get()
    x2 = entry2.get()
    x3 = entry3.get()
    label1= tk.Label(root, text = 'Sending to: ' + str(x1))
    canvas1.create_window(200,200, window=label1)

    label2= tk.Label(root, text = 'Name: '+ str(x2))
    canvas1.create_window(200,220, window=label2)

    label3= tk.Label(root, text = 'Course: '  +str(x3))
    canvas1.create_window(200,240, window=label3)


button1 = tk.Button(text = 'TEST', bg="black", fg="white", font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), command=PRINT)
canvas1.create_window(200,130, window=button1)


button2 = tk.Button(text = 'Verzenden via email', bg = "red", fg= "white", font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'), command=main)
canvas1.create_window(200,160, window=button2)
```

Comment: Putting all your widgets on a Canvas is a very strange approach here - the normal reason for doing that is that it allows the widgets to be scrollable, but you have nothing big enough to need scrolling.  Putting them directly in `root`, using `.pack()` or `.grid()`, is the normal approach to Tkinter layout.  Using `.grid()` just means that you need to specify a row and column number for each widget, you don't need to come up with exact coordinates for everything.

Comment: use layout managers `pack()` or `grid()` and it should automatically organize widgets in window, and resize window it they will need more space.

Comment: in code I don't see any `Label` on the left of `Entry`. How do you try to add it ? Show in your code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to place widgets at exact coordinates. Tkinter has managers for handling layout in a logical manner: `pack` and `grid`. These take care of problems with different window sizes, different resolutions, and different fonts, and are superior to placing elements at specific x/y coordinates.

Since you want to create a grid of label/entry pairs, `grid` is the correct choice.

```
entry1=tk.Entry(root)
entry2=tk.Entry(root)
entry3=tk.Entry(root)
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Sending to:")
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Name:")
label3 = tk.Label(root, text="Course:")

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
label3.grid(row=2 column=0)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was not in the country. This seems to work pretty good. But how do I implement the buttons to send the info?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the item ID of each `canvas1.create_window(...)` and then use the item ID to find the position of the entry and put a text before the entry using `canvas1.create_text(...)`:

```
...
# function to put a prompt before the 'entry' item
def create_prompt(prompt, entry):
    # get the bounding box of the Entry item
    bbox = canvas1.bbox(entry)
    # create a canvas text item and put it before the Entry item like below:
    #  (x-5,y)   (x,y)
    # -------+   +-----------------+
    #  prompt:   | Entry           |
    #            +-----------------+
    #
    # note that bbox[0] is the x-coordinate of the top-left of entry item
    #           bbox[1] is the y-coordinate of the top-left of entry item
    # using anchor='ne' means that the (x, y) of the text is the top-right corner of the text
    # and finally return the item ID of the canvas text item
    return canvas1.create_text(bbox[0]-5, bbox[1], text=prompt, anchor='ne')

entry1=tk.Entry(root)
entry1_item = canvas1.create_window(200, 60, window=entry1)
create_prompt('sending to:', entry1_item)

entry2=tk.Entry(root)
entry2_item = canvas1.create_window(200, 80, window=entry2)
create_prompt('name:', entry2_item)

entry3=tk.Entry(root)
entry3_item = canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=entry3)
create_prompt('course:', entry3_item)
...
```

Comment: @AllardvanGasteren I have added some comment and hope you understand.